# Pagination links not showing on custom post type admin list

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

In my own plugin I have a custom post type **faq**. In the admin listing are 14 faq posts. In the Wordpress Settings under Reading is **10** posts per pages set. Additionally, I have added a **pre_get_posts** function with the following content.

```php
function hep_pre_get_posts_faq(WP_Query $query)
{
    // check if current query is not the main query
    if (!$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    // edit the query only when post type is 'faq'
    if (!is_admin() || $query->query['post_type'] == 'hep_faq') {
        return;
    }

    // Protect against arbitrary paged values
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

    // set pagination
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    $query->set('paged', $paged);
}
```

The list is displayed correctly with 10 entries. Where the pagination links are, there is written **14 items** without pagination links. And this for a good reason, because if I force the display you see **1 of 1**. But here should be **1 of 2** because there are **14 posts**.

This already happened to me with another cpt. The strange thing here is that everything works fine on the live-system on the server. Only on the local development-system it doesn't display the pagination links because of the same reason as described above.

Of course this confuses me a lot. As it seems not to be the code, because it's exactly the same on the development system as on the live system.

I would be very happy for any help concerning this. The plugin is already live and is used productively by my customers.

Here are all query parameters:

```
Request
/wp-admin/edit.php
?post_type=hep_faq

Query String
post_type=hep_faq
&posts_per_page=20

Query Vars
cache_results   1
comments_per_page   50
lazy_load_term_meta 1
order   DESC
paged   1
post_type   hep_faq
posts_per_page  10
update_post_meta_cache  1
update_post_term_cache  1
```

and the custom post type arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'faq',
    'description'         => 'FAQ',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array('title'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'capabilities'        => $caps,
    'public'              => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
    'show_in_menu'        => 'hep-dashboard',   
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 1,
    'menu_icon'           => plugins_url() . "/img/contact.png",
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => array('hep_faq', 'hep_faqs'),
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array('slug' => get_option('hep_faq_slug')),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Posts per pages*" limit from "*Settings* -> *Reading*" does not apply here (post list in the dashboard) and default size of list is **20**.

Your pagination does not work properly because you use `pre_get_posts` action hook to change the **per_page** limit, which is not the right way. The **per_page** limit overwritten by `pre_get_posts` filter will only work in some situations (it will not work, for example, for hierarchical types) and it will affect number of posts fetched from DB, but in pagination original **per_page** value will be used.

### Posts per page in dashboard

To change the number of posts per page for the lists in a dashboard, use hooks:

- [edit_posts_per_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_posts_per_page/)
- [edit_{$post_type}_per_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_post_type_per_page/)

```
add_filter('edit_hep_faq_per_page', 'se337791_hepfaq_posts_per_page');
function se337791_hepfaq_posts_per_page( $posts_per_page )
{
    return 10;
}

// -- OR --
add_filter('edit_posts_per_page', 'se337791_posts_per_page', 20, 2);
function se337791_hepfaq_posts_per_page( $posts_per_page, $post_type )
{
    if ( 'hep_faq' == $post_type )
        return 10;
    return $posts_per_page;
}
```